# How Can I Fix Glitchy Images on Google Chrome?

Tags: image, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-app

I would like to ask about these images I found to be glitchy on google chrome.

I must confirm that none of these are intentional.

This started since I saw a glitchy image on my google classroom, here are some images I found to be glitchy. I don't seems to find a pattern from them.

- [Glitchy image on google classroom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJQI8.png)
- [How the google classroom image should look like (my friend's perspective)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JXW7.png)
- [Broken logos of chrome extensions (fullscreen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxobw.png)
- [Broken search icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypMZb.png)
- [Broken pdf icon on web.whatsapp.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCO7Y.png)

It sometimes manages to fix itself though, I successfully took a screenshot of glitchy icons and the normal ones.

- [Search Icons, both normal and glitchy displayed at the same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkc5f.png)

I've tried to delete images cache and even reinstalled chrome, none of them works to fix this problem.

Some information that might help narrow down the problem:

- I've recently used this PC with a new SSD (I've used it for about a month now), which contains the chrome itself, and it works properly so far. I don't think this should be a problem with the disk. (please correct me if I'm wrong)
- However, on the day this happens, I installed the React Devtool (I've deleted it though) (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) and the Redux Devtools (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd)

Can this problem be a bug on the chrome itself, or perhaps something related with skia? Should I report this as a problem to Chrome, or is this a problem on my end?

Information about my OS and Google Chrome (I'll provide more if it is required):

OS:

Edition:    Windows 10 Pro
Version:    20H2
Installed on:   ‎1/‎10/‎2022
OS build:   19042.1526
Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0

Chrome:

Version: 98.0.4758.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Thanks

**EDIT: Fixed, I changed from using GPU 0 to GPU 1 via settings, is this a graphics card compatibility issue?**

- GPU 0: Intel(R) HD Graphics 530
- GPU 1: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M

Answer (score 0):

Setting **"Choose ANGLE graphics backend"** (chrome flag) to **"OpenGL"** fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I managed to fix it by relaunching chrome through this(I attached the step by step youtube video and the screen I got):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkMTH_Y6ecw&t=54

[image]